# is this possible to select two table in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a project like Wikipedia in PHP and I don't know what to do
about this problem

This is my schematic database,

```
'items'                 
+-----+----------+--------------+
|id   | item_name| item_require |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|1    | branch   |  2, 3        |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|2    | log      |  1, 3        |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|3    | root     |  1, 2        |
+-----+----------+--------------+
```

How do I get the branch requirement like example below
in my PHP

```
+===============================+
|   branch requirements         |
|        *log                   |
|        *root                  |
+===============================+
```

Comment: Hi Khai, you should consider using a pivot table, as it looks like you are relating those records.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is all about your database structure. You should create a ManyToOne relationship like :
items (id, name) and requirements (id_item, id_requirements)

Then, you can query easily your requirements with :

```
SELECT name from items INNER JOIN requirements ON items.id = id_requirements WHERE id = YOUR_ID
```